# Trying to create list of objects, operator = is giving me trouble

Tags: c++

Consider following class :

```
class Subject
{

private:
    char* name; // I must use char pointers, it's for school.
    int grade;

public:
    Subject() {
        name = NULL;
        grade = 0;
    }
    Subject(char *n, int g) {
        name = new char[strlen(n)];
        strcpy(name,n);
        grade = g;
    }
    ~Subject() {
        delete name;
    }
    void operator=(const Subject &obj) {
        strcpy(name, obj.name);
        grade = obj.grade;
    }
}
```

So  it is pretty simple data structure with its special functions. I'm new
       to overload operators so it is probably not correctly implemented.
       Now, what I try to do is make a simple array of those objects. 
       Consider my main function :

```
Subject *collection = new Subject[3];
char tmp[100];
int grade;

for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i ++){

   cin >> tmp;
   cin >> grade;

   collection[i] = new Subject(tmp,grade);
}
```

This returns error saying no match for operator= in ..etc. So I get that they don't know what to do when they see '=', so I need to define it. How do I do it. Again, point is to make simple list of Subject objects.(I can't use vector, it is for school)

Comment: `new Subject` returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated `Subject`. `new Subject[3]` is an array of 3 `Subject` objects (*not* an array of 3 `Subject *`).

Comment: Is your teacher in the conviction that he is teaching C++, by the way?

Comment: "it is for school" is a bad reason to have to not learn modern C++.

Comment: he believes we should first learn to implement String DS, before using one.

Comment: `name = new char[strlen(n)];` Your array is too short by one. It needs an extra element for the null terminator. Gazillions of duplicates about that kind of thing here.

Comment: thanks, can you help me. How do I make array of objects

Comment: Imagine what would `strcpy` inside your `operator =` do if you tried copying a subject called `"Physical education"` in place of a subject called `"Math"`?

Comment: @Chiel: SO is not a forum. And teaching the complexities of pointers so that students understand the merits of a solution like `std::string` is not necessarily a bad idea. You don't appreciate a solution if you have never experienced the problem. A professional C++ programmer should prefer `std::string` **and** have an idea of how it is implemented, or rather **because** he or she has an idea of how it is implemented (including the fact that it does not use `new[]`, for example).

Comment: By the way, `delete name` invokes undedined behaviour. It must be `delete[] name`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. the `operator=` should not return void:

   ```
   Subject& operator=(const Subject &obj){
       grade = obj.grade;
       strcpy(name, obj.name);
       return *this;
   }
   ```
2. `Subject *collection = new Subject[3];` this creates an array of 3 `Subjet` objects. Operator `new`, however, returns a pointer to a new object created on the heap, so:

   ```
   collection[i] = new Subject(tmp,grade);
   \___________/   \____________________/
        ^                    ^-----a pointer to a Subject object
        |--object of Subject type
   ```

   you are trying to assign a pointer to an object, which is not going to work. To make your `operator=` work, you should write `collection[i] = Subject(tmp,grade);`
3. This line `strcpy(name, obj.name);` will cause undefined behaviour if `obj.name` is larger than `name`. You should change the `name` size accordingly before copying the strings.
4. It would be a good idea to read about the so-called [rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) of [three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). Basically, if your class defines either the destructor, the copy constructor or the copy assignment operator, it probably should define all of them.

Comment: I see you didn't say anything about name in operator= function, only grade. Why is that?

Comment: @nhrnjic6, that was a typo

Comment: It works. I want to thank you sir, I know it's a pain dealing with this basic stuff, but you helped me alot.